# ssh: Identity not Loaded from Keychain at Startup

Tags: git, ssh

I have configured a host in my `~/.ssh/config` like this

```
Host pptest
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_test_2048_pp
UseKeychain yes
AddKeysToAgent yes
```

This key has a passphrase on it. As was my understanding, `UseKeychain` and `AddKeysToAgent` should automatically load the keys passphrase on reboot, however I have not found this to be the case. To get for instance a `git-fetch` (or any remote action involving ssh) working, I still need to run an

```
ssh-add
```

beforehand.

Why is this happening?

My system is `10.15.5 (19F96)`

Comment: What host name is `git-fetch` actually using to connect? It sounds like your block isn't being processed when `ssh` runs.

Comment: `git@pptest:user/repo.git`. But it does work after I do a `ssh-add`, so if the host wouldn't be recognized, I could not connect at all.

Comment: That sounds like `git` isn't using your `.ssh/config` for some reason. `ssh-add` configures your agent so that the correct key is used, even if `config` had no entry for `pptest`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work, as [illustrated here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/275432).

I would add the `User` and `Hostname` to your config entry.
And, as explained in "[Solving ‘UseKeychain’ Not Working for Password Protected SSH Key Logins on macOS](https://wesley.sh/solving-usekeychain-not-working-for-password-protected-ssh-key-logins-on-macos/)" from [Wesley David](https://wesley.sh/wesley-david-consultant/), I would use the full path for the key.

```
Host pptest
  IdentityFile /Users/<me>/.ssh/id_rsa_test_2048_pp
  UseKeychain yes
  AddKeysToAgent yes
  User git
  Hostname actual/url/for/pptest
```

The URL would then be:

```
pptest:user/repo.git
```

And I would make sure to test it manually first

```
ssh-add -K /Users/<me>/.ssh/id_rsa_test_2048_pp # check it prompt for a passphrase
# reboot
# then check a git ls-remote pptest:user/repo.git works
```

David mentioned:

> You may want to try first adding your key with ssh-add -K using the full filesystem path to the key. 
>   Then you may want to remove any other references to the key file in Keychain Access that use relative paths.

Comment: Using absolute paths did nothing, however adding it with `ssh-add -K` worked. It remembers the key now. Never had to do this manually before though...